# Oracle APEX and ORDS Listener

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Currently have a deployment of APEX 5.1.1.00.08 where I need to change the web listener from the default Embedded PL/SQL Gateway to ORDS.

Anyone knows which version of ORDS works with APEX 5.1.1.00.08? Does Oracle have an official literature which details version compatibilities?

(WebLogic version is 12.2.1.2.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Oracle APEX 5.1 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/installing-AE-and-configuring-Oracle-REST-data-services.htm#HTMIG29143) ("Application Express Installation Guide" -> "Installing Application Express and Configuring Oracle REST Data Services"):

> Oracle Application Express release 5.1 requires Oracle REST Data Services release 2.0 or later.